# triggers pl sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I am trying to create trigger. I need to satisfy the following requirements:
there is a table with the columns `action` and `price`.

And requirements for trigger:

o   In case of `action` column is filled with “purchase”, price is filled by price of mm

o    In case of `action` column is filled with “detailimpression”,  price is filled by price of SKU

How to create trigger for the particular value in field?

Answer (score 2):

Such business logic should not be implemented via trigger, but in BL layer.